# Condition tests in a do while loop

Tags: java

I have a program which contains a do while loop. I need to test if either one of two conditions arise. The first is that currentPlayerEnergy does not equal 0. The second is that quit does not become true. The code is as follows:

```
do
{
        switch(answer)
        {
            case 'w':   System.out.println("Walk");
                        break;

            case 'b':   System.out.println("Buy");
                        break;

            case 'c':   System.out.println("Change Character");
                        break;

            case 'r':   currentPlayerEnergy = 0;
                        break;

            case 'q':   quit = true;
                        break;
        }


}
while ( (currentPlayerEnergy > 0) || (quit != true ) );
```

Note that I'm just testing currentPlayerEnergy becoming zero in the case 'r'. I understand the problem, java reads the test and says that if current energy is not zero, continue with the block but it then won't check whether quit has become true. Am I using the wrong type of loop? Is there some other operand I should be using instead of logical or? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there some other opera[tor] I should be using instead of logical or?

Yes, the correct operator to use is the logical "AND" (`&&`):

```
while ( (currentPlayerEnergy > 0) && !quit );
```

I've also changed `(quit != true)` to `!quit`, but this change is purely stylistic.

Comment: thankyou so much! I've been going over and over this! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are telling the programm here:

```
 while ( (currentPlayerEnergy > 0) || (quit != true ) );
```

Is that if one of the two boolean expressions is true stay within the while.

Only if both are false it will continue. You would want the logic to do exactly what [aix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/aix)
said:

```
while ( (currentPlayerEnergy > 0) && !quit );
```

note that (!quit) is only a short form of (quit != true)